# In VS Code (Go extension), where do I run commands?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

From here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/GOPATH-in-the-VS-Code-Go-extension

> At any point in time, you can run the command Go: Current GOPATH to see the GOPATH being used by the extension.

**But... WHERE do I type that command?**

Is there a specific command pane I need to open or something?

(I'm on the Mac client, if that's relevant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Shift Command P, that is the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

From there, type that command.

But, GOPATH is a lot less important with recent Go versions that support [Go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, there are some limited commands with the extension cmd+shift+p but if you want the full range of commands just open the terminal and run what you need.

If you are looking for custom tasks like building in a certain way them up can create them in vscode. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Comment: cmd+shift+p is the answer I was looking for.  Your advice about the terminal is not relevant, because those are totally different commands.